# Lerna + npm packages - how do I run npm install of the build?

Tags: node.js, build, lerna, npm-workspaces, npm-ci

I've created a monorepo project with server/client/shared packages.
I have an existing (large) project that I try to apply monorepo behavior to have common code between multiple projects.

I'm using *npm wordspaces* (I know `yarn` has better support but existing codebase must use npm) and `lerna`. The *server* project has dependency to the *shared* project with this entry in depdencies: `"@myProj/shared": "*"`.

I use `tsc` to buld the project and output to a `build` folder. Then I want to copy the `package.json` to the build folder, and run `npm ci` to generate the production *node_modules*. But when I'm in `dist` - npm doesn't know of the shared project and it fails.

```
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@myProj%2fshared - Not found
```

What is the best way to build the sared project with the server project, or to at least refer to it when running the npm ci?